# How do I upload an mp4 file to s3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nestjs

I am attempting to upload an mp4 file to S3 using Javascript S3Client the same why it is uploaded from selecting the "Upload" button in AWS Console. When I uploaded the mp4 from the AWS Console somehow the file is accessible as an mp4 file, and clicking on the Object URL link will play the video in the browser, see screenshot 1

***Screenshot 1***
[image]

However when I try to upload the file from the NodeJS server, I am not able to get the same result. I have attempted using the following code which is what I have found in several examples on the internet.

```
const test = await this.s3Client.send(
  new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: "centralizer-mp4-cache",
    ContentType: "vidoe/mp4",
    Key: "test",
    Body: fs.createReadStream("audio.mp4"),
  }),
);
```

This doesn't seem right as it seems to be creating a key/value pair but I am not sure what other method I need to use to get the same result. When using the method in the above code, the Object URL is completely different and when selecting the link, it downloads the file, which is not what I need.

[image]

Using the AWS UI directly gives me what I need, so how do I programmatically get the same result?

Comment: Is this a typo (video vs vidoe)? `ContentType: "vidoe/mp4",`

Comment: Ok that was a good catch, it seems to play the video now but without any audio lol